# excel add in individual customized error bars

Tags: excel, confidence-interval

I am creating a bar chart in Excel with point estimates for a binary variable that is a percentage, the variable is stratified over a categorical variable (race). In the chart, I am looking for a way to add in custom error bars (i.e., custom standard error values), for each point estimate, since the percent values are estimates from complex survey data analysis.

When I added the custom error bars, for one bar, the same value is repeated across all the other bars. (Error Bars --> More Options --> Custom --> Specify Value). However, I am looking to create a confidence interval that is specific to only one bar. How would that be done in Excel?